# How to uneject C drive

Tags: windows, windows-10, eject

I ran the command `mountvol c: /D` in windows 10  and now the C drive is ejected. Even after a restart it is still ejected. Is there a way to uneject it? I do have a windows installation disk.

Answer (score 0):

You have removed the `C:` drive-letter from the system disk.

To repair, you need a Windows 10 bootable media.
If you don't have one, you may create it on another computer using the
Media Creation Tool.

Boot from the media into the Command Prompt (see
[How to Open a Command Prompt at Boot in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2880-open-command-prompt-boot-windows-10-a.html)),
locate your disk and use
[diskpart](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/diskpart)
to assign back the drive-letter to `C`:

1. Open a command prompt
2. Type in `diskpart`
3. Type `list disk` to see a list of disks
4. Type `select disk #`  (where # is the disk you want)
5. Type `detail disk` to see partitions
6. Type `select volume #`  (where # is the volume you want)
7. Type `assign letter=x`  (where x is the drive letter)

For more information with screenshots see the article
[How to Use the Diskpart Utility to Assign and Remove Drive Letters](https://www.howtogeek.com/197296/how-to-use-the-diskpart-utility-to-assign-and-remove-drive-letters/).

If all fails,
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
using the latest Windows 10 bootable media downloaded from Microsoft.